# JAX-WS webservice on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws

I am following links below to publish a webservice.

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-java-web-application-integration-example/
http://stlarch.blogspot.com.tr/2013/02/building-jax-ws-webservices-in-weblogic.html 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/ 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/

This code works when deployed on Tomcat.
But it does not work at weblogic 12c. Do I need to give additional parameters?
I am not having an exception while deploy process. I cannnot see any item one weblogic console  at Webservices section under deployed application.

UPDATE:
After deploying webservicetest.war coded by madhava

[image]

Comment: You mean you are not able to see Web Services after deployment in Weblogic server?

Comment: yes I cannot see so I cannot access the webservice via url

Comment: Try with your IP address instead of localhost. First you run CalculatorServiceClient

Comment: Does not work. Are we using same weblogic version? Do you use weblogic 12.1.3?

Comment: Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections and check your IPV4 and use the ip and try http://XXX.YYY.ZZ.AA:7001/wls_utc?wsdlUrl=http%3A%2F%2FXXX.YYY.ZZ.AA%3A7001%2FWebServicesTest%2FCalculatorServiceService%3FWSDL

Comment: :) Ofcourse I have been using this ip, but I do not think it is related to network issue

Comment: do u use weblogic 12.1.3? if so do you have any additional jar file given inthe CLASSPATH?

Comment: No I am using earlier version(I hope it should work in any other version). I have added only javaee-api-6.0 jar into my classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the following link then applied the `servlet` mapping technique.
I can access the `wsdl` and make successfuly `SOAP` request via `SOAPUI`

http://www.krestjaninoff.ru/2013/09/custom-context-path-for-jax-ws-web.html

```
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>TestWSPort</servlet-name> 
    <display-name>TestWSPort</display-name> 
    <servlet-class>name.krestjaninoff.TestWSService</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>TestWSPort</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>myOwn/path/TestWS</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the project I have created, you can download
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vztkfqxekw43n4a/WeblogicJaxWsProject.zip?dl=0

Thanks Mikhail Krestjaninoff who is owner of the post given by link above

Comment: this is good stuff most of the times you find reference impl and crap about sun-jaxws.xml but if you are using weblogic or websphere, you dont use reference impl

Comment: none of the two provided url works. Please post the full solution.

Answer (score 3):

I Have created my own application to check your issue. Indeed it is working fine for me. I am sharing the same with you.

1) Create a simple web application.(In Eclipse File+New+Dynamic Web Project)

2) Create an interface as a webservice.

```
package com.madhava.service;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.madhava.CalculatorServiceConstant;
@WebService(name = CalculatorServiceConstant.Name.CALCULATOR_SERVICE, targetNamespace = CalculatorServiceConstant.CALCULATOR_SERVICE_TARGET_NAME_SPACE)
public interface CalculatorService {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="sum")Integer addNumber(@WebParam(name = "number1") Integer number1,
            @WebParam(name = "number2") Integer number2);

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="difference")Integer subtractNumber(@WebParam(name = "number1") Integer number1,
            @WebParam(name = "number2") Integer number2);

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="multiplication")Long multiplyNumber(@WebParam(name = "number1") Integer number1,
            @WebParam(name = "number2") Integer number2);

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="division")Double divideNumber(@WebParam(name = "number1") Integer number1,
            @WebParam(name = "number2") Integer number2);
}
```

3) Create a class which implements the webservice which you have written.

```
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.jws.WebService;

    import com.madhava.service.CalculatorService;

    @Stateless
    @WebService(portName = CalculatorServiceConstant.PortName.CALCULATOR_SERVICE, serviceName = CalculatorServiceConstant.ServiceName.CALCULATOR_SERVICE, endpointInterface = CalculatorServiceConstant.EndPointInterface.CALCULATOR_SERVICE, targetNamespace = CalculatorServiceConstant.CALCULATOR_SERVICE_TARGET_NAME_SPACE)
    public class CalculatorServiceImpl implements CalculatorService {

        @Override
        public Integer addNumber(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
            if (number1 != null && number2 != null) {
                return number1 + number2;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Integer subtractNumber(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
            if (number1 != null && number2 != null) {
                if (number1 > number2) {
                    return number1 - number2;
                } else {
                    return number2 - number1;
                }
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Long multiplyNumber(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
            if (number1 != null && number2 != null) {
                return (long) (number1 * number2);
            } else {
                return 0L;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Double divideNumber(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
            if ((number1 != null && number2 != null) || number2!=0) {
                return (double) (number1 / number2);
            }
 else {
                return 0.0D;
            }
        }

    }
```

4)Create a Class which keeps the name, portname, service name etc.

```
public class CalculatorServiceConstant {

    public static final String CALCULATOR_SERVICE_TARGET_NAME_SPACE = "http://calculatorservices.madhava.com";

    private CalculatorServiceConstant() {

    }

    public static class Name {
        public static final String CALCULATOR_SERVICE = "CalculatorService";

        // Private Constructor
        private Name() {

        }

    }

    public static class PortName {
        public static final String CALCULATOR_SERVICE = "CalculatorServicePort";

        // Private Constructor
        private PortName() {

        }
    }


    public static class ServiceName {

        public static final String CALCULATOR_SERVICE = "CalculatorServiceService";

        // Private Constructor
        private ServiceName() {

        }
    }


    public static class EndPointInterface {

        public static final String CALCULATOR_SERVICE = "com.madhava.service.CalculatorService";

        // Private Constructor
        private EndPointInterface() {

        }
    }



    public static class JNDI {

        public static final String CALCULATOR_SERVICE = "CalculatorService#com.madhava.service.CalculatorService";

        // Private Constructor
        private JNDI() {

        }
    }

}
```

5)Create a war file of the application and deploy the same in weblogic server. Here you will be able to see the webservice as 'CalculatorServiceService'

[image: CalculatorService]

Url to test client in weblogic:

```
http://localhost:7001/wls_utc/?wsdlUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7001%2FWebServicesTest%2FCalculatorServiceService%3FWSDL
```

6)Finally to check whether it is working properly or not I have created the client class.

```
package com.madhava.client;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import com.madhava.CalculatorServiceConstant;
import com.madhava.service.CalculatorService;

public class CalculatorServiceClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7001/WebServicesTest/CalculatorServiceService?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName(CalculatorServiceConstant.CALCULATOR_SERVICE_TARGET_NAME_SPACE, CalculatorServiceConstant.ServiceName.CALCULATOR_SERVICE);

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        CalculatorService calculatorService = service.getPort(CalculatorService.class);

        System.out.println(calculatorService.addNumber(10,20));

    }

}
```

Hope it helps you !

Comment: could you share web.xml as well?

Comment: I have addded your class file into my project , but still does not see anything webservices section. Here is my project, could you compile and deploy? https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5x7wtit3ieqxel/WebServicesExample.7z?dl=0

Comment: can you share your war file with me?

Comment: For a time being you forget about mkyong's project. Now you please try create a new project as I have mentioned above and check whether it is working or not. My internet is dead slow right now(I will upload once my internet is fine). I have done only those above mentioned steps in my project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, after deploying I am able to see the CalculatorWebservice at Webservices section, but it is not provided since when I try to access it it gives 404 error. pls look at my screen shot at questions updated.

Comment: I have also use office laptop and use static ip, I cannot access the service with static IP either

Comment: :) Ofcourse I have been using this ip, but I do not think it is related to network issue since after adding index.jsp into war file, I can see the content via http://10.250.0.47:7001/WebServicesTest

Comment: this is very simple, but if you need a soap handler, weblogic docs want you to do some crazy jwsc ant task gen stuff, really?